# Design Time Model is not same with the Run Time Output

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm using Visual Studio 2022, VB.Net Framework 4.7.2 . As title said, when I design, I have insert a button with showing all the text, but when I run it, the button only show partial of the text. And for the display resolution, why my form when design time is very clear, but it will turn blur when run time. How to make it is clear whether it is design time and run time?
How can i solve these problem?

1. How to make the button display all of the text? I mean the run time should display all exactly what the design time display.
2. How to make the run time looks as clear as design time?

[image: The button should display all of the text but it doesn't work]

[image: Notice that the left side is design time, is more clear than right side which is run time]

Comment: Is the problem the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/832052)?

Comment: I think that is for C#

Comment: The C# in that answer should be trivial to translate to VB.  Are you running into a specific problem with it?

Comment: @Craig yes and no. The C# code `Application.Run(new Form1());` doesn't have an equivalent in VB because that is handled silently (Program.cs vs no VB analog). However a VB project does have settings similar to a C# project and that is the part that OP could look into. That part should be language agnostic

Comment: @djv There's no need to PInvoke, just set the DpiAwareness mode. In `app.config`, in this case, since the OP is targeting .NET Framework 4.7.2. That question has answers that also mention this -- In any case, if necessary, in VB.NET one can use the `MyApplication` class to do that (e.g., overriding `OnStartup()`), in case the Application Framework is up. Otherwise, it's the same as C# (i.e., you start explicitly from `Main` and call the same initialization methods)

Comment: @Jimi `There's no need to PInvoke` we're on the same page